# WordPress - Show custom logo on login screen

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm trying to add a custom logo to my wordpress login form. I've a child theme active and I've used the following code inside my `functions.php` file, anyway the code will be ignored and I will see always the default wordpress logo. Is there something wrong in the code or I need to put this into the functions file of the parent theme?

```
function add_custom_logo(){
 ?>
  <style type="text/css">
    #login h1 a, .login h1 a {
        background-image: url('https://www.example.org/logo.png');
        height: 65px;
        width: 320px;
        background-size: auto;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
     }
  </style>
 <?php
}
add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_logo');
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the case, this cause by the priority issue - please change your action hook into this and try again:

```
add_action('login_enqueue_scripts', 'add_custom_logo', 99);
```

Comment: Just tried now, cleared cache using the plugin that was instelled by the agency who created the site, but the default logo will not change.